# Passing 2D arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I have received an assignments and although not specified I would like to implement the use of pointer in it. My problem that I am encountering is that I believe I am not passing my 2D array correctly a second time. What I mean by second time is that I would like to pass the array from main to a function and then again from this function to a different function (if anyone knows of some appropriate terminology of doing this I would appreciate if you can share it.) Since I already wrote a bunch of other code, I will provide the method of how I am passing it, if I am doing it correctly I will provide the remaining of the code in order to find if there is another bug within the code.

```
int main(){
    char seats[rows][columns] //rows and columns are global integers
    assignSeats(&seats);
}
void assignSeats(char (*sPlan)[rows][columns]){
    assignFirstClass(sPlan);
}
void assignFirstClass(char (*sPlan)[rows][columns]){
    //user inputs for row and col
    (*sPlan)[row][col] = 'X';
}
```

Just to mention, I am not getting any error, just that I am not getting the value I am giving to the array position. Although the bug could be somewhere else I would first like to confirm that I am doing the passing of the array correctly since this is what is new to me. Thank you in advance for your help.

**SOLUTION**
The problem was not with the method of passing the pointer, simply that instead of:

```
(*sPlan)[row][col] = 'X';
```

I wrote:

```
(*sPlan)[row][col];
```

It just went pass me multiple times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Comment: yeah I've seen it, and that's how I did the first pass. It does not however address the second pass. This is where my inquiry is.

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function) for the different approaches to passing a 2D array

Comment: I did but I also read that the method I am using (*arrName)[rows][cols] is a better method and would like to learn in this way.

Comment: The parameter is correct for the second pass. However your functions are lacking return types

Comment: sorry, all those functions are actually set to void except main which is set to int, I will edit this on my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your array by reference by replacing your call with `assignSeats(seats);` and changing your function parameter to `assignSeats( char (&sPlan)[rows][columns]`, do the same for your second function.

Your functions also need return types, and you are missing a bracket in your second function definition.

Suggested fix:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char seats[rows][columns]; //rows and columns are global integers
    assignSeats(seats);
    std::cout<<seats[row][col];  //Check the function has worked
    return 0;
}

void assignSeats(char (&sPlan)[rows][columns])
{
    assignFirstClass(sPlan);
}

void assignFirstClass(char (&sPlan)[rows][columns])
{
    //user inputs for row and col
    sPlan[row][col] = 'X';
}
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't do it either.

Comment: @ Jorge what result are you expecting and how are you checking for it?

Comment: @ nitronoid after the function assignSeats(seats) in the main function I call another function to print the current values. Also before this assign I initialize all to '*'. When I print it before assignSeats(seats) I get all *. This is why I know the first passing is working properly. I am expecting an 'X' in a row and col selected by the user in the assignFirstClass function which I am not getting.

Comment: @Jorge The current code prints an X for me, can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: @nitonoid I was about to copy all the code and then found the mistake I was doing. Since you gave me the most help I made your answer as the solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad you found the solution.